# The [colors] argument must not be null. If [stops] is non-null, it must have the same length as [colors]

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Estou recebendo esse erro acima quando passo uma variável cor do tipo Color para criar um gradiente, como mostrado abaixo.

**widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  CategoryItem(this.title, this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Text(title),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [color.withOpacity(0.7), color],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ))); // error on this line
  }
}
```

**classe onde declaro a variável cor**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  const Category({required this.id, required this.title, this.color = Colors.orange});
}
```

Comment: Sua classe `CategoryItem` estende a classe [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) não possui controle de estado, é anotada como [`@immutable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/meta/Immutable-class.html) e portanto não permite alterações em suas propriedades. Aqui na propriedade `colors: [color.withOpacity(0.7), color]` os elementos da lista devem ser constantes.

Answer (score 0):

Remova o `const` do decoration. Como você está passando valores dinâmicos ele não pode ser constante.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Text(title),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(     /* <---- Aqui */
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [color.withOpacity(0.7), color],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Sempre que você adiciona um const todos os widgets da árvore ficam constantes, mas algum deles recebe parâmetros você deve remover o const dos widgets 'pais'

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).